# MYSQL nested JSON, INSERT_INTO issue

Tags: mysql, json, sql-insert, mysql-8.0

I'm sending an object to the stored procedure and there I'm doing INSERT_INTO table, everything working fine until I added a new field.

Previously JSON looked something like this:

```
'[{ "id": "asdsadsa", "something": "asdasdasd"}]'
```

Now I added a new field that is a JSON object and this is how it looks parsed from the Server sent to the stored procedure (JSON.stringify):

```
'[{ "id": "asdsadsa", "somedata": "{\"newField\":\"something\"}}"]'
```

And I'm mapping this filed inside the stored procedure like this

```
somedata JSON PATH "$.somedata"
```

After Adding this field I started getting this issue 
[image]

NOTE!!: IF I remove "" from the object so have object passed like this 
`"somedata": {\"newField\":\"something\"}}` everything works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: ```"{\"newField\":\"something\"}}"``` is not an object, but a  string. Also i believe the last quotes on  ```"{\"newField\":\"something\"}}"``` should be before the last curly braces, this is probably what that error is referring to.

Comment: This was generated from JSON.stringify, how should I avoid it?

Comment: can you show the code where you stringify it? also the object before being stringified.